# is there any possibility of security vulnerability in storing "window.name" in browser sessionstorage

Tags: javascript, html, browser

Consider 2 different applications with different domains. In a browser window, I will access app1 it will store the `window.name` in into session storage client side.

```
sessionstorage.set("name", window.name);
```

Now I will open app2 in the same window, where its client side JS tries to access the "name" value from session storage:

```
var a = sessionstorage.get("name");
```

In this case, will it give null value or a valid value (set through app1)?

I understand that it gives valid value only if both applications have same origin/domain.

Comment: This question makes absolutely no sense, it claims to understand session storage can't be shared between domains and then asks if it is. And why not just go and test this with two domains.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. Session storage and local storage (web storage) are domain local (separate for each domains). Values set in one domain can only be read on that domain. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) clearly states that the session and local storage are tied to current origin.

> The read-only sessionStorage property accesses a session Storage object for the current origin. sessionStorage is similar to localStorage; the difference is that while data in localStorage doesn't expire, data in sessionStorage is cleared when the page session ends.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).